# Thread safety in Set obtained from a cache

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I stumbled upon the following piece of code:

```
public static final Map<String, Set<String>> fooCacheMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

this cache is accessed from rest controller method:

```
public void fooMethod(String fooId) {
    Set<String> fooSet = cacheMap.computeIfAbsent(fooId, k -> new ConcurrentSet<>());
    //operations with fooSet
}
```

Is `ConcurrentSet` really necessary? when I know for sure that the set is accessed only in this method?

Comment: The question is not if the set is only accessed in this method but whether two threads may access the set simultaneously. You can run this code in parallel in multiple threads, who knows.

Comment: "when I know for sure that the set is accessed only in this method?" Except that you don't, because `fooCacheMap` is `public`.

Answer (score 2):

As you use it in the controller then multiple threads can call your method simultaneously (ex. multiple parallel requests can call your method)

As this method does not look like synchronized in any way then ConcurrentSet is probably necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

> Is ConcurrentSet really necessary?

Possibly, possibly not. We don't know how this code is being used.

However, assuming that it is being used in a multithreaded way (specifically: that two threads can invoke `fooMethod` concurrently), yes.

The atomicity in `ConcurrentHashMap` is only guaranteed for each invocation of `computeIfAbsent`. Once this completes, the lock is released, and other threads are able to invoke the method. As such, access to the return value is not atomic, and so you can get thread inference when accessing that value.

In terms of the question "do I need `ConcurrentSet"? No: you can do it so that accesses to the set are atomic:

```
cacheMap.compute(fooId, (k, fooSet) -> {
  if (fooSet == null) fooSet = new HashSet<>();
  // Operations with fooSet
  return v;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a concurrent map will not guarantee thread safety. Additions to the Map need to be performed in a synchronized block to ensure that two threads don't attempt to add the same key to the map. Therefore, the concurrent map is not really needed, especially because the Map itself is static and final. Furthermore, if the code modifies the Set inside the Map, which appears likely, that needs to be synchronized as well.

The correct approach is to the Map is to check for the key. If it does not exist, enter a synchronized block and check the key again. This guarantees that the key does not exist without entering a synchronized block every time.

Set modifications should typically occur in a synchronized block as well.

Comment: You can and even should make additions to the ConcurrentHashMap without synchronized block. Implementation of ConcurrentHashMap guarantees you a thread-safety. Locking it with synchronized will only degrade performance.

Comment: "to ensure that two threads don't attempt to add the same key to the map" is the relevant point.